# Android HTTP Request RSS Feed

Tags: android, json, http, rss-reader

I am trying to make a RSS Feed ANDROID app where i download the source code from a website. However, it shows error in DefaultHttpClient,HttpPost, HttpResponse and HttpEntity. I have imported them manually as well but no change. Please Help me!

```
  import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
  import org.apache.http.HttpResponse; 
  import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
  import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
  import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
```

Code:

```
   try {
        // defaultHttpClient
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        is = httpEntity.getContent();

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        json = sb.toString();
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: those classes have been removed in android 6

Comment: Use [Volley](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yhv8l9F44qo).

Comment: It gives error for RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);